# $1 not containing a value

Tags: regex, perl

I’m writing a script that uses regexes to identify and pull out sets of years in various different formats from a text file. Here’s the bit of code in question:

```
if ($parts[0] =~ /^\(*(\d\d\d\d)\)*$/) {
    # Matches a single 4 digit date in parentheses such as (1979)
    $start = $1;
    $end = $1;
} 
elsif ($parts[0] =~ m{\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\d\d} ) {
    # Matches cases like 1948/1972
    warn "Found a $1";
    #do some other stuff
}
```

The problem I’m encountering is that it finds dates matching the expression in the `elsif`, but `$1` doesn’t hold the value, *i.e.*, it prints out a `"Found a "` message over and over, but with no value for `$1`. Could anyone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong here? I apologize if it’s a stupid mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using parentheses to capture $1 . Try this `elsif ($parts[0] =~ m/(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)/ ) {` . Also you can use `\d{4}` instead of `\d\d\d\d`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, enable warnings.

It isn't setting `$1` because you are not capturing anything in the `m{\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\d\d}` regex.  Perhaps you mean to be doing `m{(\d\d\d\d/\d\d\d\d)}`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture a match with `()` before actually using with `$1` in `elsif` part.

In addition, regex can be shortened as follows:

```
if ($parts[0] =~ /^\(*(\d{4})\)*$/) {
    # Matches a single 4 digit date in parentheses such as (1979)
    $start = $end = $1;
} 
elsif ($parts[0] =~ /^(\d{4}\/\d{4})$/ ) {
    # Matches cases like 1948/1972
    warn "Found a $1";
    #do some other stuff
}
```